# Task.Delay vs Thread.Sleep for suspending System.Timers.Timer's job

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, task

I've jumped into discussion: what is better to use for suspending the job of System.Timers.Timer for 1 second in cycle, Task.Delay or Thread.Sleep???

Here is sample case:

```
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (Connection.IsAlive) return true;
  }
};
```

Please help me with arguments :)

Comment: What happened when you tried the two approaches?

Comment: If you are taking advantage of async await then using await Task.Delay you dont have to block a thread.  If that piece of code is going to be hit concurrently i'd consider it, else I might not bother.

Comment: How do you define which is "better" ?

Comment: "better" means - the correct one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is.

`Thread.Sleep` will block the system thread that is in use. By default System.Timers.Timer uses the system thread-pool, meaning you wouldn't block your main thread, and the use of `Thread.Sleep` *probably* will execute concurrently with the rest of your program. If you desire is to use (and therefore block) a specific thread, you will need use the [SynchronizingObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx) property, in coordination with `Thread.Sleep`.

`Task.Delay` will provide a logical delay without blocking the current thread. This is the best approach, unless you have a reason to block a specific thread. Keep in mind you'll need to make your event handler asynchronous to use `Task.Delay`:

```
 timer.Elapsed += async (sender, args) =>
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
         {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            ...
         }
    }
```